# How to set one variable of data in an array

Tags: java, arrays, series

I have been trying to set a bunch of data (numbers) in a variable, then tried to set this variable into an array so that I don't to change those variables every time I run the programme (the user inputs data, and this data is stored into one variable. My array takes the variable as a set of data).

I have been asked to do it and the output console doesn't seem to give me what I need. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CalculTempsSelonDonneesDemandees {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    double t0,h,n=1,b;
    double t;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Initial time : ");
    t0=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Variation : ");
    h=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Nomber of terms : ");
    b=sc.nextDouble();

    while(b!=n-1) {
      t=(t0+(n-1)*h);
      n++;

      double tblT[] = {t};

      System.out.print(t+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, the user enters an intitial time, a variation of time then how many terms the user wants in his series.

It displays the times from that initial time and it stops when the number of terms is different than n (it's like an arithmetic series). When I run it, it displays t, the times. But how do I know the values of t are set in the array? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to have an array that is a list of the `t` values?

Comment: If you want to know if values are set, you can print them or look at them in a debugger.

Comment: `b` and `n` should probably be `int` instead of `double`.

Comment: @Icewind Yes that's exactly what I to do.

Comment: @GriffreyDog thank you for the hint, I totally forgot they must be int variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new array tblT for every iteration in your while loop.  tblT is a local variable in the scope of your while loop.  Each iteration the old tblT will be destroyed and a new one will be created.  If you don't know how many items you will need in your array then consider using an arraylist which can change size dynamically.  Ex.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    double t0,h,n=1,b;
    double t;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Initial time : ");
    t0=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Variation : ");
    h=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Nomber of terms : ");
    b=sc.nextDouble();
    ArrayList<Double> tblT = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while(b!=n-1) {

      t=(t0+(n-1)*h);
      n++;

      tblT.add(t);

      System.out.print(t+" ");

    }
    //tblT will now contain the elements. You can use tblT.get(index) to access the elements

}
```

Or if you know before the loop how many items there will be then you could create an array outside the loop `double[] tblT = new double[size of array here];` and initialize it with the size you need.

Comment: Since I am very new at Java, what you wrote totally makes sense. Thank you!